# Cannot add process permitted capabilities through file permitted

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

I had a problem while I was playing around with capabilities.
Basically I have a file "add.sh" which prints capabilities of the current process.
I add `cap_dac_override=eip` capabilities to the file by using root user and then I switch to an unprivileged user.

When I check process capabilities, before running add.sh, the process capabilities are:

```
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 00000000a80425fb
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

The "add.sh" file capabilities are still `cap_dac_override=eip`.

According to the Linux documentation, once executed, the script "add.sh" should have

```
P'(permitted) = (P(inheritable) & F(inheritable)) | **(F(permitted) & P(bounding))** | P'(ambient)
```

so I expected to have

```
CapPrm: (hex value for cap_dac_override)
```

Instead I still get

```
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 00000000a80425fb
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

I would like to ask you where I'm wrong.

Comment: Similarly to what happens for set-user-ID permissions, Linux does not honor capabilities interpreter scripts. You will have to create a binary executable program and set capabilities on it. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87348/capabilities-for-a-script-on-linux

Comment: We only have your evidence, but we don't have your code. Read about [mcve] before you post another question. Good luck.